# fucntion drawing svg with onclick event does not work

Tags: javascript, svg, onclick

https://jsfiddle.net/godgog/gh275nsr/52/

In the above JFD, I have 3 functions.

- The first one `graph()` is to draw a coordinate systems.
- The second one `plot(x,y)` is to draw a graph of function y = ax^2 through the point (x,y);
- The third one `intPoint()` is to draw integer points by drawing `<circle>` colored yellow.

all function work, but how can I assign each circle an `onclick()` event, which triggers the `plot(centerX,centerY)` function drawing the graph through the center of the circle?
Thanks a lot!

```js
var w = 500, h = 500;
var x0 = w/2, y0 = h/2; 
var scale = 30;
var str = '<svg width="' + w + '" height="' + h + '">';


function graph(point,project){ 

//number lines
//Ox
var x_ax = '<line x1="0" y1="' + y0 + '" x2="' + w + '" y2="' + y0 + '" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-width="2" />';
    x_ax += '<polyline points="' + (w-10) + ',' + (y0-5) + ' ' + w + ',' + y0 + ' ' + (w-10) + ',' + (y0+5) + '" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-width="1" fill="none" />';
    x_ax += '<text x="' + (w-10) + '" y="' + (y0+15) + '" font-size="15">x</text>';
//Oy
var y_ax = '<line x1="' + x0 + '" y1="0" x2="' + x0 + '" y2="' + h + '" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-width="2" />';
    y_ax += '<polyline points="' + (x0-5) + ',' + 10 + ' ' + x0 + ',' + 0 + ' ' + (x0+5) + ',' + 10 + '" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-width="1" fill="none"/>';
    y_ax += '<text x="' + (x0-15) + '" y="' + 10 + '" font-size="15">y</text>';
    y_ax += '<text x="' + (x0-15) + '" y="' + (y0+15) + '" font-size="15">O</text>';

for(var i=1; i<= Math.floor((h-y0)/scale); i++){ //horizontal lines
 str += '<line x1="0" y1="' + (y0+ i*scale) + '" x2="' + w + '" y2="' + (y0+i*scale) + '" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-width="0.5" />';
 str += '<text x="' + (x0+5) + '" y="' + (y0+i*scale - 5) + '" font-size="12">' + (-i) + '</text>';
};

for(var i=1; i<= Math.floor(y0/scale); i++){ //horizontal lines, >0
 str += '<line x1="0" y1="' + (y0- i*scale) + '" x2="' + w + '" y2="' + (y0-i*scale) + '" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-width="0.5" />';
 str += '<text x="' + (x0+5) + '" y="' + (y0-i*scale + 12) + '" font-size="12">' + (i) + '</text>';
};

for(var i=1; i<= Math.floor((w-x0)/scale); i++){ //vertical lines
 str += '<line x1="' + (x0+i*scale) + '" y1="0" x2="' + (x0+i*scale) + '" y2="' + h + '" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-width="0.5" />';
 str += '<text x="' + (x0+i*scale - 5) + '" y="' + (y0 - 5) + '" font-size="12">' + i + '</text>';
};

for(var i=1; i<= Math.floor(x0/scale); i++){ //vertical lines >0
 str += '<line x1="' + (x0-i*scale) + '" y1="0" x2="' + (x0-i*scale) + '" y2="' + h + '" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-width="0.5" />';
 str += '<text x="' + (x0-i*scale - 5) + '" y="' + (y0- 5) + '" font-size="12">' + (-i) + '</text>';
};



//points
for(i = 0; i < point.length; i++){
 str += '<circle cx="'+ (x0+point[i][1]*scale) +'" cy="' + (y0-point[i][2]*scale) + '" r="3" stroke="none" fill="red" />';
 str += '<text x="' + (x0+point[i][1]*scale+ ((point[i][1]>0)? 5 : -15)) + '" y="' + (y0-point[i][2]*scale+7) + '" font-size="16">' + point[i][0] + '</text>';

//project
if(project){
 str += '<line x1="' + (x0+point[i][1]*scale) + '" y1="' + (y0-point[i][2]*scale) + '" x2="' + x0 + '" y2="' + (y0-point[i][2]*scale) + '" stroke="#ff8080" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="7" />';
 str += '<line x1="' + (x0+point[i][1]*scale) + '" y1="' + (y0-point[i][2]*scale) + '" x2="' + (x0+point[i][1]*scale) + '" y2="' + y0 + '" stroke="#ff8080" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="7" />';
};
};

return str + x_ax + y_ax;
};

function plot(x,y){ //plot y=ax^2
var s = '';
var a = scale*(y0-y)/((x-x0)*(x-x0));
function g(x){return a*x*x}; 
 // graph
var xx1, yy1, xx2, yy2, dx = 1 //interval 
var iMax = Math.floor((w - x0)/dx), iMin = -Math.floor(x0/dx);
var color = ["green", "blue", "magenta", "aqua" , "pink"];

for (var i=iMin; i<= iMax; i++){
 xx1= dx*i; yy1 = scale*g(xx1/scale);
 xx2= dx*(i+1); yy2 = scale*g(xx2/scale);
 s += '<line x1="' + (x0+xx1) + '" y1="' + (y0-yy1)+ '" x2="' + (x0+xx2) + '" y2="' + (y0-yy2) + '" stroke="' + color[0] + '" stroke-width="1.6" />';
};
  return s;
};


//draw integer points, 
function intPoint(){
var s = '';
for(i = -Math.floor(w/scale); i < Math.floor(w/scale); i++){
 for(j = -Math.floor(h/scale); j < Math.floor(h/scale); j++){
  s += '<circle cx="'+ (x0+i*scale) +'" cy="' + (y0-j*scale) + '" r="3" onclick="plot(' + (x0+i*scale) + ',' + (y0-j*scale) + ')" stroke="none" fill="red" />';
 };
};
 return s + '';
};

var svg = str + graph([]) + intPoint() + '</svg>'

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str + graph([]) + intPoint() + plot(280,220) + '</svg>';
```

```html
<p id="demo">

</p>
```

Comment: `onLoad` - typo, JS is case sensitive, that should be all lower case.

Comment: I think it's not the main reason why it does not work, my JFD shows that the plot function is not defined, and that confuses me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that, on the click event, you are calling the `plot()` function.  All that function does is return a string with your new line definition (ie. `"<line ...>"`). You don't do anything with that string.

One way to fix this is change your `onclick` to call a new function (eg. `replot()`), which regenerates the graph completely.

```
function replot(x,y) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str + graph([]) + intPoint() + plot(x,y) + '</svg>';
}
```

Updated program:

```js
var w = 500, h = 500;
var x0 = w/2, y0 = h/2; 
var scale = 30;
var str = '<svg width="' + w + '" height="' + h + '">';


function graph(point,project){ 

//number lines
//Ox
var x_ax = '<line x1="0" y1="' + y0 + '" x2="' + w + '" y2="' + y0 + '" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-width="2" />';
    x_ax += '<polyline points="' + (w-10) + ',' + (y0-5) + ' ' + w + ',' + y0 + ' ' + (w-10) + ',' + (y0+5) + '" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-width="1" fill="none" />';
    x_ax += '<text x="' + (w-10) + '" y="' + (y0+15) + '" font-size="15">x</text>';
//Oy
var y_ax = '<line x1="' + x0 + '" y1="0" x2="' + x0 + '" y2="' + h + '" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-width="2" />';
    y_ax += '<polyline points="' + (x0-5) + ',' + 10 + ' ' + x0 + ',' + 0 + ' ' + (x0+5) + ',' + 10 + '" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-width="1" fill="none"/>';
    y_ax += '<text x="' + (x0-15) + '" y="' + 10 + '" font-size="15">y</text>';
    y_ax += '<text x="' + (x0-15) + '" y="' + (y0+15) + '" font-size="15">O</text>';

for(var i=1; i<= Math.floor((h-y0)/scale); i++){ //horizontal lines
 str += '<line x1="0" y1="' + (y0+ i*scale) + '" x2="' + w + '" y2="' + (y0+i*scale) + '" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-width="0.5" />';
 str += '<text x="' + (x0+5) + '" y="' + (y0+i*scale - 5) + '" font-size="12">' + (-i) + '</text>';
};

for(var i=1; i<= Math.floor(y0/scale); i++){ //horizontal lines, >0
 str += '<line x1="0" y1="' + (y0- i*scale) + '" x2="' + w + '" y2="' + (y0-i*scale) + '" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-width="0.5" />';
 str += '<text x="' + (x0+5) + '" y="' + (y0-i*scale + 12) + '" font-size="12">' + (i) + '</text>';
};

for(var i=1; i<= Math.floor((w-x0)/scale); i++){ //vertical lines
 str += '<line x1="' + (x0+i*scale) + '" y1="0" x2="' + (x0+i*scale) + '" y2="' + h + '" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-width="0.5" />';
 str += '<text x="' + (x0+i*scale - 5) + '" y="' + (y0 - 5) + '" font-size="12">' + i + '</text>';
};

for(var i=1; i<= Math.floor(x0/scale); i++){ //vertical lines >0
 str += '<line x1="' + (x0-i*scale) + '" y1="0" x2="' + (x0-i*scale) + '" y2="' + h + '" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-width="0.5" />';
 str += '<text x="' + (x0-i*scale - 5) + '" y="' + (y0- 5) + '" font-size="12">' + (-i) + '</text>';
};



//points
for(i = 0; i < point.length; i++){
 str += '<circle cx="'+ (x0+point[i][1]*scale) +'" cy="' + (y0-point[i][2]*scale) + '" r="3" stroke="none" fill="red" />';
 str += '<text x="' + (x0+point[i][1]*scale+ ((point[i][1]>0)? 5 : -15)) + '" y="' + (y0-point[i][2]*scale+7) + '" font-size="16">' + point[i][0] + '</text>';

//project
if(project){
 str += '<line x1="' + (x0+point[i][1]*scale) + '" y1="' + (y0-point[i][2]*scale) + '" x2="' + x0 + '" y2="' + (y0-point[i][2]*scale) + '" stroke="#ff8080" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="7" />';
 str += '<line x1="' + (x0+point[i][1]*scale) + '" y1="' + (y0-point[i][2]*scale) + '" x2="' + (x0+point[i][1]*scale) + '" y2="' + y0 + '" stroke="#ff8080" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="7" />';
};
};

return str + x_ax + y_ax;
};

function plot(x,y){ //plot y=ax^2
var s = '';
var a = scale*(y0-y)/((x-x0)*(x-x0));
function g(x){return a*x*x}; 
 // graph
var xx1, yy1, xx2, yy2, dx = 1 //interval 
var iMax = Math.floor((w - x0)/dx), iMin = -Math.floor(x0/dx);
var color = ["green", "blue", "magenta", "aqua" , "pink"];

for (var i=iMin; i<= iMax; i++){
 xx1= dx*i; yy1 = scale*g(xx1/scale);
 xx2= dx*(i+1); yy2 = scale*g(xx2/scale);
 s += '<line x1="' + (x0+xx1) + '" y1="' + (y0-yy1)+ '" x2="' + (x0+xx2) + '" y2="' + (y0-yy2) + '" stroke="' + color[0] + '" stroke-width="1.6" />';
};
  return s;
};


//draw integer points, 
function intPoint(){
var s = '';
for(i = -Math.floor(w/scale); i < Math.floor(w/scale); i++){
 for(j = -Math.floor(h/scale); j < Math.floor(h/scale); j++){
  s += '<circle cx="'+ (x0+i*scale) +'" cy="' + (y0-j*scale) + '" r="3" onclick="replot(' + (x0+i*scale) + ',' + (y0-j*scale) + ')" stroke="none" fill="red" />';
 };
};
 return s + '';
};

function replot(x,y) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str + graph([]) + intPoint() + plot(x,y) + '</svg>';
}

var svg = str + graph([]) + intPoint() + '</svg>'

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str + graph([]) + intPoint() + plot(280,220) + '</svg>';
```

```html
<p id="demo">

</p>
```

Comment: Thanks a alot. I've just got another idea, I nest the `plot` in a `<g>` tag, and it works well. https://jsfiddle.net/godgog/gh275nsr/75/

Comment: I still couldn't understand, I the `plot` or `replot` function don't work until I define `window.replot = function(x,y)` https://jsfiddle.net/godgog/gh275nsr/82/

Comment: That's just a JSFiddle issue.  If you want to call functions like that from the results pane, you have to include the Javascript in the results page.  You do that by going to the Javascript panel dropdown options and switching the "Load type" to "No wrap - bottom of <body>".

Comment: Inside which loop?  The elements don't exist until after the `innerHTML = ...`. So you would need to add the event handlers then.

Comment: iIve tried to assign functions to these `circle` elements by `document.getElementsByTagName("circle")[k].onclick = function(){alert(1)}` outside the loop. But it doesn't work. the debugger shows that it cannot  get these `circle`. I don't know why ? https://jsfiddle.net/godgog/gh275nsr/113/

Comment: This has veered off topic from the original question.  Please ask a new question.